# Convert percentage to decimal within text

Tags: r, regex, string, decimal, percentage

I have several rows of a data.frame which contain calculation rules. Within that string I need to convert text like:

```
"{p500} * 65% >= {q600}"
```

into

```
"{p500} * 0.65 >= {q600}"
```

I'm new to regular expressions, but I think *gsub* would help here.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide more different input strings, so that the solution is more generalised for other types of calculation strings, too.

Comment: my data contains several rows of a data.frame which are similar (ist always like " {} * 24% <= {}" or "{} = {} * 5%" .... what if I want to use a variable like my_dataframe$column within that gsub command? R gives no useful Output here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regmatches`. First capture those numbers that you need then divide by 100 to make them to decimal points. Then replace them by their decimal points: 
Caution. This replaces the original `str` that you had. Maybe creating a copy will be necessary:

```
 str <- c("{p500} * 65% >= {q600}","{p500} * 9% >= {q600}",
             "{p500} * 190% >= {q600}","{p500} * 2.4% >= {q600}") 
 str1=str 
 regmatches(str1,regexpr("\\d\\S*%",str))=as.numeric(sub(".*?(\\d\\S*)%.*","\\1",str))/100
 str1
[1] "{p500} * 0.65 >= {q600}"  "{p500} * 0.09 >= {q600}" 
[3] "{p500} * 1.9 >= {q600}"   "{p500} * 0.024 >= {q600}"
```

## EDIT:

if others were missing the `%` sign and they need to remain the same:

```
str <- c("{p500} * 65% >= {q600}","{p500} * 65 >= {q600}","{p500} * 9% >= {q600}",
   "{p500} * 190 >= {q600}", "{p500} * 190% >= {q600}","{p500} * 2.4% >= {q600}",
    "{p500} * 2.4 >= {q600}") 

 str1=str # Create a copy
 m=regexpr("\\d\\S*%",str)# Find only those that contain % sign

 regmatches(str1,m)=as.numeric(sub("%","",regmatches(str,m)))/100
str1
[1] "{p500} * 0.65 >= {q600}"  "{p500} * 65 >= {q600}"   
[3] "{p500} * 0.09 >= {q600}"  "{p500} * 190 >= {q600}"  
[5] "{p500} * 1.9 >= {q600}"   "{p500} * 0.024 >= {q600}"
[7] "{p500} * 2.4 >= {q600}"
```

checking the second element, the fourth element and the last element, You will see that they have not been changed.

Comment: This is also a good solution. But what if `str` also contains values which don't have a % ? This code doesn't work then. Thanks for further help.

Comment: Well that is a point that was never put across. This is a vectorized format in that there are no for loops. The answer given has `lapply` and `apply` 2 for loops at the code, meaning if the data was huge the codewould fail. Finally why would there be no %sign? Then why change to decimal. Okay if there was no percentage sign then our capturing group will be `"\\s\\d\\S*"` This can be used to capture all that you need to capture after the `*` sign and before `>` sign

Comment: if there is no % then this value oft `str` has to be skipped / remained as it is.

Comment: Wow but even the answer given does not do that. Are you looking for a code that does that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `gsubfn` to do computation on regular expressions:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d+)%", function(x) strtoi(x)/100,"{p500} * 9% >= {q600}")
[1] "{p500} * 0.09 >= {q600}"
```

Note that the capturing group values are passed to the anonymous replacement function via `x = \\1`

If your text is consistently like the example you provided you could do multiple gsubs in `base` like @snoram suggested:

```
gsub("(\\d)%","0.0\\1",gsub("(\\d{2})%","0.\\1","{p500} * 9% >= {q600}"))
[1] "{p500} * 0.09 >= {q600}"
```

The `(\\d{2})` matches exactly 2 digits and the parenthesis create a group that can be recalled later in gsub. By calling `\\1` in the replacement, you are back-referencing the group that you captured in the original string. The outside gsub `(\\d)%` matches exactly 1 digit and substitutes an additional 0 in that case.

I'm still relatively new at regular expressions myself, but I've found this cheat-sheet to be helpful: [R Regular Expressions](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: This fails on `9%`

Comment: Right, and is `0.9` equal to `9%`? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution in base-R but using (optional) `magrittr` for readability

```
# data + library
str <- c("{p500} * 65% >= {q600}", "{p500} * 9% >= {q600}")
library(magrittr)

# Apply gsub twice:
str %>% 
  gsub("(\\d{2})%", "0\\.\\1", .) %>%
  gsub("(\\d{1})%", "0\\.0\\1", .)
[1] "{p500} * 0.65 >= {q600}" "{p500} * 0.09 >= {q600}"
```

**EDIT**

Given new cases in the comments, I guess it would be best to leave the simple approach above behind and try something different. Here is a quick and dirty example (still relying on good ol' base-R):

```
# New data
str <- c(
  "{p500} * 65% >= {q600}", 
  "{p500} * 9% >= {q600}",
  "{p500} * 190% >= {q600}", 
  "{p500} * 2.4% >= {q600}")

# Quick and dirty
strmat <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(str, " "))
strmat[, 3] <- as.double(gsub("%", "", lapply(strsplit(str, " "), "[", 3))) / 100
apply(strmat, 1, paste, collapse=" ")
[1] "{p500} * 0.65 >= {q600}"  "{p500} * 0.09 >= {q600}"  "{p500} * 1.9 >= {q600}"  
[4] "{p500} * 0.024 >= {q600}"
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an adaption, if the value is like 190% and 2.4%?

Comment: Liked the challenge and came up with a new solution as fast as I could using `strsplit()` but it can definitely be done cleaner with more time (or skills).

Comment: doesn't this only work, if the percentage is always at the same Position? (so it can be split with the percentage in the 3rd col) ?  The length of the Input values may differ...

Comment: Kind of, it depends on the number of spaces being constant.

Comment: Which they are in the examples you give. You would get much better answer if your question included much more of the different forms your data can take. Regular expressions need... regularity.